# Reading .h5 file in R

Tags: r, rhdf5

I have a '.h5' file and want to extract it using R.

I searched and found `rhdf5` from `BiocManager` is used for this purpose. I tried it and I got an error. No matter if I use either 'h5ls' or 'h5read' methods, I always get the same error message below.

> Error in H5Fopen(file, "H5F_ACC_RDONLY", native = native) : 
>     HDF5. File accessibilty. Unable to open file.

```
file_url <- "data/MillionSongSubset/AdditionalFiles/subset_msd_summary_file.h5"
h5ls(file_url)
data <- h5read(file_url)
```

I want to extract my '.h5' file either csv or another type in order to use them in R.

Comment: Take a look at this [thread](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/97311/) and this [issue](https://github.com/grimbough/Rhdf5lib/issues/11).

Answer (score 1):

This is a Windows problem. I had it commonly either trying to open .tsv or .h5 processed by Kallisto (using, in my case, txtimport). Move you file of folder away from "my documents", e.g. to c:[YOURFOLDER]. That should solve your problem.